# Задача на поиск наибольшего/наименьшего элемента в области матрицы

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже запутался с этой задачей, в целом вроде работает, но иногда минимальные/максимальные элементы определяются неверно. Где ошибка? Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10][10];
    int i, j, l, k, n, maximal=-1, minimal=10;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите n" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите K" << endl;
    cin >> k;
    cout << "Введите L" << endl;
    cin >> l;
    cout << endl;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
        a[i][j] = rand()%10;
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (j = l; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] > maximal)
            {
            maximal = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (j = l; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] < minimal)
            {
            minimal = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Максимальный элемент матрицы данной области равен " << maximal << endl;
    cout << "Минимальный элемент матрицы данной области равен " << minimal << endl;
}
```

Comment: что такое `k` и `l`, и почему цикл начинается с единицы?

Comment: k и l - индексы левого нижнего элемента области

Comment: "левого нижнего" или "нижнего левого"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> k и l - индексы левого нижнего элемента области

```
minimal = a[0][l];
maximal = a[0][l];
for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)
{
    for (j = l; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] > maximal)
        {
            maximal = a[i][j];
        }
        if (a[i][j] < minimal)
        {
            minimal = a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: все работает, большое спасибо!

Comment: @Shinkiro На здоровье. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.